# Cmake test gets ignored - building cmake project with gradle in android

Tags: android, c++, gradle, android-ndk

I'm trying to integrate https://github.com/j0r1/JRTPLIB into gradle. There's already a tutorial on the readme about how to compile the library to installation on Android, but I need gradle integration.

Here's how I added the project to my gradle file:

https://github.com/lucaszanella/jscam/blob/ecc99f430b360f7e1aa5bf687633a5e3557c045e/src/jscam/android/app/build.gradle#L118

I'm getting a compilation error because my system libs don't have support for `ifaddrs`. However, the cmakelists of the project has a test for that:

```
jrtplib_include_test(ifaddrs.h RTP_SUPPORT_IFADDRS "// No ifaddrs support")
```

**So why is gradle trying to build something that didn't pass the test?**

Here's the error while compiling my app:

```
Error while executing '/android-sdk-linux/cmake/3.6.4111459/bin/cmake' with arguments {--build /home/project/src/jscam/android/app/.externalNativeBuild/cmake/debug/x86 --target jrtplib-shared}
  [1/3] Building CXX object src/CMakeFiles/jrtplib-shared.dir/rtpudpv4transmitter.cpp.o
  [2/3] Building CXX object src/CMakeFiles/jrtplib-shared.dir/rtpudpv6transmitter.cpp.o
  FAILED: /android-sdk-linux/ndk-bundle/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/clang++  --target=i686-none-linux-android --gcc-toolchain=/android-sdk-linux/ndk-bundle/toolchains/x86-4.9/prebuilt/linux-x86_64 --sysroot=/android-sdk-linux/ndk-bundle/sysroot  -DJRTPLIB_COMPILING -Djrtplib_shared_EXPORTS -I/home/project/src/jscam/JRTPLIB/src -Isrc -isystem /android-sdk-linux/ndk-bundle/sources/cxx-stl/gnu-libstdc++/4.9/include -isystem /android-sdk-linux/ndk-bundle/sources/cxx-stl/gnu-libstdc++/4.9/libs/x86/include -isystem /android-sdk-linux/ndk-bundle/sources/cxx-stl/gnu-libstdc++/4.9/include/backward-isystem /android-sdk-linux/ndk-bundle/sysroot/usr/include/i686-linux-android -D__ANDROID_API__=16 -g -DANDROID -ffunction-sections -funwind-tables -fstack-protector-strong -no-canonical-prefixes -mstackrealign -Wa,--noexecstack -Wformat -Werror=format-security   -O0 -fno-limit-debug-info  -fPIC -MD -MT src/CMakeFiles/jrtplib-shared.dir/rtpudpv6transmitter.cpp.o -MF src/CMakeFiles/jrtplib-shared.dir/rtpudpv6transmitter.cpp.o.d -o src/CMakeFiles/jrtplib-shared.dir/rtpudpv6transmitter.cpp.o -c /home/project/src/jscam/JRTPLIB/src/rtpudpv6transmitter.cpp
  /home/project/src/jscam/JRTPLIB/src/rtpudpv6transmitter.cpp:1575:2: error: use of undeclared identifier 'getifaddrs'
          getifaddrs(&addrs);
          ^
  /home/project/src/jscam/JRTPLIB/src/rtpudpv6transmitter.cpp:1588:2: error: use of undeclared identifier 'freeifaddrs'
          freeifaddrs(addrs);
          ^
  2 errors generated.
  FAILED: /android-sdk-linux/ndk-bundle/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/clang++  --target=i686-none-linux-android --gcc-toolchain=/android-sdk-linux/ndk-bundle/toolchains/x86-4.9/prebuilt/linux-x86_64 --sysroot=/android-sdk-linux/ndk-bundle/sysroot  -DJRTPLIB_COMPILING -Djrtplib_shared_EXPORTS -I/home/project/src/jscam/JRTPLIB/src -Isrc -isystem /android-sdk-linux/ndk-bundle/sources/cxx-stl/gnu-libstdc++/4.9/include -isystem /android-sdk-linux/ndk-bundle/sources/cxx-stl/gnu-libstdc++/4.9/libs/x86/include -isystem /android-sdk-linux/ndk-bundle/sources/cxx-stl/gnu-libstdc++/4.9/include/backward-isystem /android-sdk-linux/ndk-bundle/sysroot/usr/include/i686-linux-android -D__ANDROID_API__=16 -g -DANDROID -ffunction-sections -funwind-tables -fstack-protector-strong -no-canonical-prefixes -mstackrealign -Wa,--noexecstack -Wformat -Werror=format-security   -O0 -fno-limit-debug-info  -fPIC -MD -MT src/CMakeFiles/jrtplib-shared.dir/rtpudpv4transmitter.cpp.o -MF src/CMakeFiles/jrtplib-shared.dir/rtpudpv4transmitter.cpp.o.d -o src/CMakeFiles/jrtplib-shared.dir/rtpudpv4transmitter.cpp.o -c /home/project/src/jscam/JRTPLIB/src/rtpudpv4transmitter.cpp
  /home/project/src/jscam/JRTPLIB/src/rtpudpv4transmitter.cpp:1813:2: error: use of undeclared identifier 'getifaddrs'
          getifaddrs(&addrs);
          ^
  /home/project/src/jscam/JRTPLIB/src/rtpudpv4transmitter.cpp:1826:2: error: use of undeclared identifier 'freeifaddrs'
          freeifaddrs(addrs);
          ^
  2 errors generated.
  ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.
```

Comment: I don't know why the downvote since it's possibly not a problem with the library but how to integrate it which is exactly what I'm trying to learn

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Android NDK has `<ifaddrs.h>` for you. But the missing functions, like **getifaddrs()**, are available for `__ANDROID_API__` **24** and higher, while your projects sets **__ANDROID_API__=16**.

If your library will be used with **minSdkVersion** below 24, you cannot use these functions. Unfortunately, JRTPLIB doesn't seem to have such granular support for ifaddrs, but you can force **RTP_SUPPORT_IFADDRS** off if you choose to.

Comment: You mean forcing it off in the cmakelists.txt or inside gradle? I'm searching a way but in the google site it only talks about -D variables. I tried with them: https://pastebin.com/t757MtEE but still got the error. So I guess the only way is to edit cmakelists? Didn't want to touch the library folder...

Comment: Ok, I did RTP_SUPPORT_IFADDRS=, and did unset(RTP_SUPPORT_IFADDRS) in cmakelists and it worked

Comment: But how did you know these things about android ndk having a header file and other things?

Comment: I happen to have NDK installed, and ran `find ${NDK_ROOT} -name ifaddrs.h -exec grep getifaddrs {} \;`